# How to set the selected value of multiple MVC dropdownlist in the view without passing unique selectlists for each

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my viewmodel I have a lot of rows. I need the user to select an employee from a dropdownlist for each row. The list of employees to choose from is the same for each row, like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Rows)     
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.EmployeeID, Model.EmployeeSelectList, "-- Choose --", new {id = "employee_" +  item.ID })
...
}
```

and the model looks something like this:

```
public class TheViewModel
{
public SelectList EmployeeSelectList {get;set;}
public List<Row> Rows {get;set;}
}
```

Do I really need to have my SelectList in my Row Class instead to be able to set the selected value without using javascript or am I missing something?

The reason for asking this question is off course that the amount of redundant data sent to the client would be a lot.

As pointed out to me in the comments below, the HTML is rendered at the server anyway so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Your model doesn't get sent to the client.

Comment: I didn't include the code loading my model, but I do send it to the client. It all works, just that I'd like to avoid sending the list for each row.

Comment: I meant your model gets sent to the view, the view renders HTML and that gets sent to the client. I don't know what you mean then. Can you show in HTML what you mean?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it a little bit more clear. 

Perhaps this is not possible. It just seems silly to pass the whole list of employees for each row when it's just the selected value I'd like to change for each row.

The HTML is not the problem. I can solve this in Jquery, but it just seems hacky.

Comment: `SelectListItem` has a property named `Selected`,just set one `SelectListItem` of your `Model.EmployeeSelectList` `Selected`,then use `@Html.DropDownList` will be ok.

Comment: Yes... but I'm trying to avoid sending the whole list for each row. That is what my question is about.

Comment: but you really need so many dropdownlists right?I am confused about 'that the amount of redundant data sent to the client would be a lot',you mean the dropdownlist has too many items and you are afraid of so many dropdownlists will make page slow?

Comment: Yes jarvanJiang. The idéa to send redundant data is what bothers me. Say I have 100 rows with 20 employees to choose from. Instead of sending 20 employees once, I'm sending it a 100 times. Just because I'd like to change an integer on each row. Perhaps it does not matter... Maybee it's just because I grew up when 16K was a massive amount of data.... but I still can't help feeling it is wrong somehow :)

Comment: That does seems logical, thanks for the clarification. You can send the dropdown once and try to duplicate it with JavaScript, I wouldn't know of another way from the top of my head.

Comment: I think you get the wrong idea.Actually the `SelectListItem` won't send to client,the loop of your `Model.Rows` and the create of dropdownlists are all done in server,what sent to client are the html code.So in your case i don't think there is anything wrong beacuse as you need so much dropdownlists the final html code you should sent will not reduce unless your initialize your dropdownlist once and using javascript copy it in client.

Comment: JarvanJiang.... I'm an idiot.... I totally was in winform mode thinking.... You are right off course. The Html renders on the server anyway. I'll go hang my self now.. Thanks for being so patient.

Answer (score 0):

jarvanJiang helped me to clarify this to me as you can see in the conversation under the question. Thank you!

The answer is: It is not possible.

Its because it does not matter as all the HTML is rendered at the server anyway. And each row has the  with all its -tags when they are sent to the client. By this time it is not redundant data any more, it is just the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for add extra property in your model and you can get the ddl selected value there !

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => **Model.SelectedValue**, Model.EmployeeSelectList, "-- Choose --", new {id = "employee_" +  item.ID })
...


public class TheViewModel
{
public SelectList EmployeeSelectList {get;set;}
public List<Row> Rows {get;set;}

**public int SelectedValue{get;set;}**
}
```

Now You select any values in your dropdown ,the values had add in the `SelectedValue` property for

**Controller**

```
int selvalue=yourModelObject.SelectedValue;
```